# How to Create Light Beam Glow Effect?

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode, lighting

I want to create this effect

[image]

Simply adding an emission color or adding a light doesn't seem to create the same thing.

Is this just a plane with a lower opacity?

Or what is the best method to recreate this light beam that looks like there's a giant light coming from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with volumetrics but as your image looks rather cartoony, what you can do is create a cylinder and give it a material with a mix between *Emission* and *Transparent BSDF* with a *Separate XYZ* as factor:

[image]

[image]

If you want to add transparency to the periphery, add a new *Mix Shader*, plug the *Transparent BSDF* and use an *Input > Layer Weight* node as factor:

[image]

[image]

If you use Eevee you can put a bit of *Bloom* effect, and to have transparency you'll need to choose the *Alpha Blend* option in the *Material panel > Settings > Blend Mode*.

For the object blocking the ray you could cheat with an object that you put above the obstacle, give it a mix between *Emission* and *Transparency*:

[image]

A more realistic way to do it is to use volumetrics (works for both Cycles and Eevee): Create a cube, give it a material with a *Shader > Principled Volume* that you plug into the *Volume* input of the *Material Output*. Lower down the *Principled Volume Density* value. Create a *Spot* light.

[image]

If you don't want the volumetric to affect other parts of your scene, and if you want straight rays, give your volumetric material to a cylinder (put underneath an *Area* light with *Shape > Disk*):

[image]

Comment: so it kinda works however, if there's another object around the light, it basically cuts through the object instead of being blocked off like a normal light. Is there a way to make the "light" cylinder from intersecting other objects and act as if it were a normal light instead? Like if I add a plane in the middle, the light would still pass through the plane instead of being blocked off

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it with this method, you can do it with volumetrics though, are you planning to use Eevee or Cycles?

Comment: I can use cycles

Comment: do the volumetrics work with a empty cube too?

Comment: also, I'm confused where the green light is being applied to? for the spot light or the cube only? because when I did the volume to my cube it just made it transparent

Comment: I've given the color to the volume but you can give it a white or grey color and give the color to the light. Also you could create a cone that has the shape of the spot cone if you don't want your volumetric to affect other parts of your scene