# How would you get this light beam effect?

Tags: materials, lighting

I need to create this kind of light beam style render and I was wondering if it was possible in Blender or if it should be done in post/AE.

I tried different approaches but I'm not getting a good result.

-First approach: volumetric cube: The rest of the light in scene gives it a very washed out look. Maybe isolating just the top emissive part and compositing after could look good.

-Second approach: I tried also adding a particle system with some planes. Each plane had a light beam with an alpha channel but didnt work out.

Do think there's a better way to do it?

Thank in advance,
Jose
[image]

Comment: There are probably a few ways you can do this through "traditional lighting" (volumetrics and whatnot), however, I think it would be most easily accomplished by using a high brightness for the "light source" and then run the render result through a _Glare_ node in the compositor. Unless there's some special reason you're trying to avoid post, I think this would be the easiest way.

Comment: you could use this trick (a Layer Weight as factor between an Emission and a Transparent): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227887/how-can-i-make-cone-look-more-like-light ... same topic: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260698/how-to-create-light-beam-glow-effect